# mousemove event, access to this context

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, events, ecmascript-6

Fisrt of all I'm using D3js inside a React component so I use some variable of my class to save datas e.g.: this.graphicalId = 'test';

I have two items in my d3 element, `svgViewport` which is a g element and `streams` which are path elements. I have `.on('mousemove'` event handle for each.

In the `streams` event I would like save the name of the current stream using `d3.select(this)` (note I'm in a function() and not an arrow function so this is local) in a global variable in order to use it in the `svgViewport` event.

My problem is that like I'm in a function() `this` is local and not link to my class instance so I can't save the value in a member variable `this.currentStreamName`.

A bit of code :

```
svgViewport.on('mousemove', function (d, i) {
    if (mouseIsOverStream) {
        let mousex = d3.mouse(this);
        mousex = mousex[0];
        // here I want this of the class instance context
        this.nearestTickPosition, this.currentStreamName = findNearestTickPosition(mousex);
    }
});
```

Do you have some advices to deal with it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrow functions to get access to the instance's `this` context and still acquire the current DOM element. For the DOM element you resort to the little-known and often overlooked [third parameter](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_on) of the event listener. As the docs have it (emphasis mine):

> the specified listener will be evaluated for the element, being passed the current datum (*d*), the current index (*i*), and the **current group (*nodes*)**

Since the current index `i` is the pointer into the current group `nodes` you can refer to the current DOM element as `nodes[i]`.

Your code thus becomes:

```
svgViewport.on('mousemove', (d, i, nodes) => {
    if (mouseIsOverStream) {
        let mousex = d3.mouse(nodes[i]);  // get the current element as nodes[i]
        mousex = mousex[0];
        // this now refers to your instance
        this.nearestTickPosition, this.currentStreamName = findNearestTickPosition(mousex);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the class context in a variable out of the event binding. Then, make an IIFE and bind it's context to the stored one.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const ctx = this;
  svgViewport.on('mousemove', function (d, i) {
    if (mouseIsOverStream) {
      let mousex = d3.mouse(this);
      mousex = mousex[0];
      !function () {
        // here I want this of the class instance context
        this.nearestTickPosition, this.currentStreamName = findNearestTickPosition(mousex);
      }.bind(ctx)();
    }
  });
}
```

Also, this should work too:

```
componentDidMount() {
  svgViewport = ...;
  svgViewport.on('mousemove', (d, i) => {
    if (mouseIsOverStream) {
      let mousex = d3.mouse(svgViewport); // here
      mousex = mousex[0];
      this.nearestTickPosition, this.currentStreamName = findNearestTickPosition(mousex);
    }
  });
}
```